# intellij idea wants git username and password for every git command

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have a problem. When i write git pull to the terminal, intellij idea wants username and password for every time. I am using ubuntu 20.04. What can i do?
I tried to set email and name for globally in git.
I tried to add ssh key to the my github account.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eat3z.png)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store, you can use the `git-credential-store - Helper` to store your credentials indefinitely on the disk for use by future Git programs.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
```

[Now automatically without credentials prompt]

```
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
[your credentials are used automatically]
```

Your password will be store without encryption as plain text on the disk, protected only by filesystem permissions.